# Android Studio JSON obtain data

Tags: android, json, android-studio, kotlin, coroutine

I am using this API as a test for obtaining JSON API data. I know how to obtain the data of one of the values "grnd_level" in "list".

Here is the code I used to obtain the "grnd_level" value:

```
val weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray("list")
            for (i in 0 until weatherArray.length())
            {
                val grndlevel: Int

                val dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i)

                val temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject("main")
                 grndlevel = temperatureObject.getInt("grnd_level")
```

But I am not sure on how to obtain the value of "name" in "city"
Very new to this so any basic help would be appreciated.

Here is an image of the API JSON:
[API Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k98fM.png)

Comment: Please do not post code as images ...

Comment: I guess you should read about https://github.com/google/gson or https://github.com/square/moshi
It is easy way to parse JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root object is `forecastJson`, you are getting `list` array from it. The `city` object is on the same level as `list` array, so you can get `city` object from `forecastJson` as well:

```
val city = forecastJson.getJSONObject("city")
```

And then `name`:

```
val name = city.getString("name")
```

Comment: Even though this works for me, but i not sure why is JSONArray not supposed to be used for "city"

Comment: It's because `city` is an object not array, it is defined in json like: `"city": { ... }`. Array is defined like `"list": [...]`

Answer (score 0):

Forget using getJSONArray and getJSONObject.
I think it's better to use Kotlin Serialization:

```
    val data = Project() 
    val string = Json.encodeToString(data)  
    


    // Deserializing back into objects
    val obj = Json.decodeFromString<Project>(string)
```

You can learn about it [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization).
When you use this strategy, you improve readability of your code, and you have better access to properties.